# Set default gravity for children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains about 10 `TextViews`. I want the text of each `TextView` to be right justified. For now I have added `android:gravity="right"` for each of the `TextViews`, but I would like to have a better way out.

I would like to specify the alignment (or even style) of the all the children in the parent itself, so that all the children in the layout have the same style (instead of specifying the style separately for each children). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below article. You can declare styles in order to save yourself from headache

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I know how to use styles, but even then I would have to write `style="@style/mylabel"` for each of the TextViews. What I want is a shortcut to apply the style attribute to all the children in a layout.

Comment: In web as well you must have to give class attribute to the control. So you cant get rid of this thing.

Comment: Not even from the code? Is there any way to get all the children of a layout?

Comment: you can get view.getChildAt attribute in Layouts. You can get all the counts as well view.getChildCount.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinearLayout and specify: `android:layout_gravity="right"`

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity

Comment: That would align the view to the right inside the container. That is not what I want, please read the question again.